# WPF Two Way Binding - Still Exists After Class Disposed

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

**Code Description**

In WPF I have created a class with some properties.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace wpfBindingTest_TwoWay
{
    public class ClassTest
    {
        public String myValue { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The Window that contains the elements that need binding has the following:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _clTest.myValue = "Value";
    this.DataContext = clTest;
}

private ClassTest _clTest = new ClassTest();
public ClassTest clTest 
{
    get { return _clTest; }
    set { _clTest = value; }
}
```

I call the "binding Window" (from the Main Window) when a button is clicked:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WindowTest windowTest = new WindowTest();
        windowTest.ShowDialog();
    }
```

The binding is two-way and is implemented in the XAML as follows:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding myValue, Mode=TwoWay}" ...
```

As expected, after loading, the textbox shows: "Value".

**My Problem**

If a value is changed in the bound textbox I want the object property to change also so that if the user clicks a SAVE button the changes can be saved to a database. This happens.

**However**, my problem is that if the user closes the window and then reopens it the changes still exist, even if I set the class to null on the closed event.

What I would like to happen is for the changes made to be forgotten when the window is disposed.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You will need to show more code. I could think of at least 3 possible mistakes to show the behaviour you mention.

Comment: Thank you @nvoigt. I have updated the question with all the code.

Comment: are you sure you are not setting clTest property from somewhere else also?

Comment: I don't see any code where either your data is set to null, recreated or set to it's former value. Why do you expect your data to change back when you close the window? The window set it once to it's new value and as long as you don't change it back, it will stay that way.

Comment: @nit Yes, you are right. In the actual code I am passing the equivalent of clTest from the MainPage. I have temporarily got around this problem by creating a shallow copy for the duration of the "bound" window which will copy the class back if the save button is pushed but won't bother if it isn't. Thank you for your help.